# I cannot load my custom styles in my plugin in my wordpress site

Tags: php, css, wordpress, plugins

I am trying to call my custom styles in my wordpress plugin. I tried the wp_enqueue methods but i could not find my style sheet getting loaded.

I have tried examples from stackoverflow itself but it is not working for me.
I checked the enqued styles using debug bar - dependancy tool and cannot find the styles in that too. Please check the link for my enqued styles . [debug bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7fP6.png)
The following are the two different ways, i tried to load my css.

```
function wp_adding_styles1()
{
wp_enqueue_style('my_eastern_charts_stylesheet', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'eastern_charts_stylesheet.css');   

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_adding_styles1');

function wpb_adding_styles() {
wp_register_style('my_stylesheet', plugins_url('eastern_charts_stylesheet.css', __FILE__));
wp_enqueue_style('my_stylesheet');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_styles' );
```

[Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKKYy.png)

Comment: Can you share your directory structure? where is your css and where is this code has been written? It seems like it must work.

Comment: You are trying to load this style in front end, right? If yes, then please check the header.php file and add wp_head() function if you have not added

Comment: HI Aki, The following is the structure C:\wamp64\www\vedic\wp-content\plugins\predictions

Comment: @JaiminPanchal: wp_head() function is already added to header.php file.

Comment: @Aki: Please find the directory structure.[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKKYy.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code :

```
function your_namespace() {
 wp_register_style('charts_stylesheet',plugins_url('charts_stylesheet.css',__FILE__ ));
 wp_enqueue_style('charts_stylesheet');
}

add_action( 'wp_head','your_namespace');
```